# Trigger click on link with 'download' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have some links like this:

```
<a class="download-link" href="/some/file.mp3" download="file.mp3">download></a>
```

When this link is clicked, the file is downloaded with no prompt.

I'm trying to make a "download all" button, but I'm failing because it's seemingly not possible to trigger on a click on these links.

For example:

```
$($("a[download]")[0]).trigger("click")
// this shows no error, but the file is not actually downloaded
```

According to [this article](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-the-download-attribute/) from 2013, it is possible to trigger clicks on download links in Chrome. Has this been deprecated? Is there an alternative approach?

By the way I'm using Chrome 52. Ideally I'd find something that works on Chrome for Android as well.

My suspicion is that it is not possible, because then websites could download all sorts of malicious files if they want to. However since a 'download all' button is a common use case, I'm wondering if there is some working approach. I don't need to trigger the initial click - the "download all" button will be clicked by the user, and this will trigger the subsequent clicks.

---

To try it your self, go to https://maxpleaner.github.io/my_music/ and type the following script in the console: `$($("a[download]")[0]).trigger("click")`

Comment: If the does not work, you could consider using a window.open and making sure the server is sending a mime type for the file to force a download.

Comment: @j_mcnally I'm using a static server - github pages. Not sure how I'd set the mime type in this situation. Using rawgit I get [this url](https://cdn.rawgit.com/MaxPleaner/my_music/master/audio/dissonant-protean/dissonant-protean-0f7aea45-71a7-467a-8239-a5c419c7a487.mp3) for one of my mp3s, but it plays the song instead of downloading it.

Comment: actually your code fails with this error: Cannot read property 'trigger' of null(…); Your backend is written in php?

Comment: @Caius this is a static application hosted on Github pages. It's compiled with Ruby but there is no real "back end". Your assertion that my code "actually fails" with some other error is wrong. I put instructions to try it yourself, and I wrote my Chrome version.

Comment: @maxpleaner maybe I've found a solution, still testing.

Comment: can you have jquery enabled? I'm trying to run some jquery code but it's failing...

Comment: did you try $($(".download-link")[0]).click();

Comment: ok, my bad. I see that you're using the 3.x. I've tried to add an ID to a element and then use vanilla js to trigger the click. If you can edit the DOM with the loop adding an incremental id to each 'downloadable' link, then you can loop all the links and trigger the .click()

Comment: @NicolasEpaminonda doesn't work. It returns `r.fn.init {}` and doesn't download anything

Comment: @Caius thank you - using vanilla js was the suggestion made in rvighne's answer too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure how jQuery does it, but the following vanilla JavaScript successfully downloads every link on the page:

```
for (let link of document.querySelectorAll('a[download]'))
    link.click();
```

Chrome then prompts me if I want to download multiple files, and it works.

[image: Google Chrome download multiple files prompt]

Though you may want to warn users before doing this, as it makes the browser somewhat sluggish.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on my android phone's chrome. I have a blackberry priv.

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes, mobile browsers are likely to not have some of the newer features that desktop browsers do. In that case, you're probably out of luck... (unless you have a fallback server-side method of providing the download).

Comment: turns out it works on the Ghostery android browser, but not Chrome android or "Chrome Dev" android.

Comment: @maxpleaner It's possible the browsers you're testing it on don't support the ES6 features I'm using in this answer. If so, try this equivalent ES5 code: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[download]'), function (link) { link.click(); });`

Answer (score -2):

You have missed a dot for the CLASS in ".download-link"

```
$($(".download-link")[0]).trigger("click")
```

Comment: while you're correct that there was a typo, adding the dot does not solve the problem. To try it your self, go to [https://maxpleaner.github.io/my_music/](https://maxpleaner.github.io/my_music/) and type the following script in the console: `$($("a[download]")[0]).trigger("click")`